# Unable to connect to Neo4j db using gremlin - Error instantiating Neo4j Database

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I am new to the neo4j-gremlin. I have downloaded the latest version of tinkerpop-3.3.1 and neo4j-community-3.3.3 on Windows machine.

I followed the installation instructions given on the tinkerpop site for Neo4j-Gremlin and was able to install neo4j-gremlin plugin but when i try to connect to the neo4j graph.db using `gremlin console(graph = Neo4jGraph.open('C:/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db'))`

I get the following error. Also the display stack trace option is also not available. It jumps directly to gremlin prompt. Any thoughts?

```
Error instantiating Neo4j Database for C:/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bring this setup with gremlin-server running Neo4j plugin. You can look at my GitHub project https://github.com/achandak123/gremlin-orm-neo4j. Don't worry about the README version talking about 2.3 n all. This works with tinker pop 3.3.1 and neo4j plugin